# In my date time value I want to use regex to strip out the slash and colon from time and replace it with underscore

Tags: python, regex, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Python, Webdriver for my automated test.  My scenario is on the Admin page of our website I click Add project button and i enter a project name.

Project Name I enter is in the format of `LADEMO_IE_05/20/1515:11:38`
It is a date and time at the end.

What I would like to do is using a regex I would like to find the / and :
and replace them with an underscore _

I have worked out the regex expression:

```
[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}
```

This finds 2 digits then `/` followed by 2 digits then `/` and so on.

I would like to replace `/` and `:` with `_`.

Can I do this in Python using import re? I need some help with the syntax please.

My method which returns the date is:

```
def get_datetime_now(self):
            dateTime_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%x%X")
            print dateTime_now #prints e.g. 05/20/1515:11:38
            return dateTime_now
```

My code snippet for entering the project name into the text field is:

```
project_name_textfield.send_keys('LADEMO_IE_' + self.get_datetime_now())
```

The Output is e.g.

```
LADEMO_IE_05/20/1515:11:38
```

I would like the Output to be:

```
LADEMO_IE_05_20_1515_11_38
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to use regex? Can't you simply replace all `/` and `:` characters with underscore? And why not just format the date with underscores when you first compute the date?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just format the datetime using `strftime()` into the [desired format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%y%H_%M_%S")
'05_20_1517_20_16'
```

Comment: That works superb.  I didn't need to use regex.  This way is much simpler.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Another simple option is just using string replace :

```
s = "your time string"
s = s.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "_")
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

i) use strftime with the format:

```
strftime("%m_%d_%y_%H_%M_%S")
```

ii) simply use replace() method of strings to replace '/' and ':' to '_'

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer, but it *adds nothing* to the discussion considering other answers have already been posted that show each approach.

Comment: If you notice the time stamps all were posted about the same time....I only realized after posting that a similar just got posted :) did not feel like deleting

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want ton replace every unadvised character by an underscore. To do it, instead of using regex, you could simply use the `str.replace` method. For example:

```
out_string = in_string.replace('/', '_').replace(':', '_')
```

In this example, the first replace returns a string with all the slash replaced, and the second call replace the colons. I think it's the simplest way for replacing one or two characters. But, if you want your program to be able to evolve, I advise you using `re.sub`, as follows:

```
# first we compile the regex, for speed sake
# this regex match every one of the bad characters, and it's modular: just add one, in case
bad_characters = re.compile(r'/|:')

# your code

# replacement
out_string = re.sub(bad_characters, '_', in_string)
```